# Process Builder vs Trigger

Tags: trigger, process

what is the difference between Process Builder and Trigger? There are lot of answers out there but these are that much accurate....

Answer (score 0):

Finding a difference as simple as that if you know their capabilities and limitations. A process builder can be created by a Salesforce admin and for a trigger, you will need developer skills. In a trigger, you can do everything including the things which are possible with process builder.

You can go through the following link-
[Difference between PB and Trigger](http://www.adhiman.com/process-builder-vs-apex-triggers-choosing-between-automation-tools/)